# MongoDB model.save() returns no error and hangs indefinitely

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hi all I am having a rather strange issue. I have verified I am able to establish a connection to MongoDB, that my post action is routing from my html form to express, and that my model and schema look correct. When I fill out and try to submit the form the webpage hangs forever and does nothing. I have verified the IP is whitelisted, the connection user has full permissions, and that I could create the collection by hand via the mongo shell. I am stuck.

Here are my versions:

MongoDB: 3.4 on Atlas.

```
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"express": "~4.15.5",
"express-session": "^1.15.6",
"mongodb": "^3.0.1",
"mongoose": "^5.0.0-rc1",
"morgan": "~1.9.0",
"pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
```

My flow is html form > express router > model.save() for mongodb. Here are the source files I am using:

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Post = require('../models/post.js');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'xxx' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res){
var postData = new Post(req.body)
console.log(postData);
    postData.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Author successfully saved.');
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

post.js

```
var url = "mongodb://admin:xxxxxxx@xxx.mongodb.net:27017,xxx.mongodb.net:27017,xxx.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin";

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// create a schema
var postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    company: String,
    email: String,
    desc: String,
    tags: String,
    created: { 
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

// the schema is useless so far
// we need to create a model using it
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

// make this available to our users in our Node applications
module.exports = Post;
```

Log output from container:

```
[0mPOST / [0m- [0m- ms - -[0m
{ created: 2018-01-04T14:43:49.755Z,
_id: 5a4e3da5890164111d2ad4ee,
title: 'I am good',
company: '1900',
desc: 'Jjj',
email: 'xxx@gmail.com',
tags: 'Kkkkk' }
```

Comment: Did you try 4.13.8 version of mongoose?

Comment: I have not, let me try that and I will update the question. Good Idea.

Comment: I have looked your code again and you didn't use `res.send()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from express [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#response-methods):

> The methods on the response object (res) in the following table can
>   send a response to the client, and terminate the request-response
>   cycle. **If none of these methods are called from a route handler, the
>   client request will be left hanging.**

that's mean you need to render something to the client in order to end request/response cycle:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    var postData = new Post(req.body);

    postData.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.end('Author successfully saved.');
    });
});
```